# How do I "install dependencies" in Eclipse "using File > Import > Install Software Items from File" to setup a bootstrap workspace for Mylyn?

Tags: eclipse, installation, mylyn

I'm following the [Eclipse Mylyn Open Source Project](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/)'s [instructions for setting up a "bootstrap" ("self-hosting") workspace](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Mylyn/Contributor_Reference#Self-hosting). But I'm stuck on the third step:

- Install dependencies using File > Import > Install Software Items
  from File: mylyn-bootstrap.p2f

I select File > Import and expand all the folders in the Import dialog, and don't see "Install  Software Items from File". (I do see "Team Project Set" from the fourth step, under the Team folder.)

Are these instructions assuming I've installed something other than "Eclipse 3.7 or later" from the first step?

I'm running an (as yet) unmodified "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, Version: Helios Service Release, Build id: 20110218-0911".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Helios (3.6) is too old. *Install software items from file* was [introduced in 3.7](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/whatsNew/platform_whatsnew.html).

You could still open that file in an editor and copy/paste the update site URLs into Eclipse, so you could install the plugins manually. However, there is a high chance that already the first component (BIRT 3.7) does not install on your Eclipse 3.6.

I would generally recommend to setup one Eclipse installation per Eclipse project where you want to contribute, as they differ heavily in their dependencies and supported runtimes (e.g. either requiring Juno as dependency, or supporting everything back to 3.4).

Comment: Oops. I was the one making the wrong assumption: that I was using Eclipse 3.7 or later.